# Issue with RabbitMQ when using Multithreading: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ and need to send some messages to the queue.
So if I send just a single message it works fine.
But I need to test how it works if I have lots of the messages sent at the same time, so I created a simple app that sends messages using multithreading.
The function for sending the messages is absolutely the same as the one used in the case when I send just a single message, the only difference is that now I call this function in Task.
And I get the error message once I run my app. It says: Additional information: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
in the line:    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())

And these are the initial lines where I send the messasge:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { 
HostName = Constants.RabbitQueueHostName ,
Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort
};

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection()){
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()){
...
```

So it's a kinda weird. Usually I use MSMQ and never had such an issue with MSMQ..
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without the using statements as an experiment?

See also:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html

> Channel instances are safe for use by multiple threads. Requests into a Channel are serialized, with only one thread running commands at a time. As such, applications may prefer using a Channel per thread instead of sharing the same Channel across multiple threads. An important caveat to this is that confirms are not handled properly when a Channel is shared between multiple threads. In that scenario, it is therefore important to ensure that the Channel instance is not accessed concurrently by multiple threads.

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/rabbitmq-amqp-channel-best

> Channels are not thread safe. You should create and use a channel on a single thread. You should be especially careful when mixing server and client-originated methods.  Invoking publish inside a deliver handler would be an example.